# How do I make my quiver plot more representative of the data ie. with clear arrows?

Tags: python, netcdf

I am trying to make a quiver plot out of my data, a NETCDF file. However, the vector representation of the data is no good. I want to have small vectors and no zero-value vectors which appear as dots.

I tried playing around with different parameters of quiver function, this plot is the clearest one I have: [plot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooxFk.jpg)

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
from pylab import *
import numpy as np

nest_1_filename = "nests/expt_91.2-1.nc"

# Reading the nest data.
ncid_1 = Dataset(nest_1_filename, "r+", format = "NETCDF4")

# Getting the values of Longitude from the nestfile.
lon_1 = ncid_1.variables['lon']

# Getting the values of Latitude from the nestfile.
lat_1 = ncid_1.variables['lat']

# Getting the values of U-velocity from the nestfile.
zu_1 = ncid_1.variables['water_u']

# Getting the values of V-velocity from the nestfile.
zv_1 = ncid_1.variables['water_v']

# Removing single-dimensional entries.
mask_1 = squeeze(zu_1[0][0][:][:])
mask_2 = squeeze(zv_1[0][0][:][:])

X, Y = np.meshgrid(transpose(lon_1), transpose(lat_1))  
quiver(X, Y, mask_1, mask_2, angles='xy', scale_units='xy', scale = 1, headwidth=25, headlength=10, minshaft = 50)
```

I expect the output to be something like this.[plot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnJsW.jpg)

The NETCDF file used here: [link](http://ncss.hycom.org/thredds/ncss/GLBu0.08/expt_91.2?var=water_u&var=water_v&north=-45&west=-30&east=30&south=-80.0000&horizStride=1&time_start=2016-04-18T00%3A00%3A00Z&time_end=2016-04-19T00%3A00%3A00Z&timeStride=1&vertCoord=1&addLatLon=true&accept=netcdf)

Comment: Try: quiver(X, Y, mask_1, mask_2, angles='xy', scale_units='xy', scale = 2, width = 0.00008)

Answer (score 0):

You would have to adjust the scale and the width of the arrows. Try scale = 0.33, width = 0.003. Ignore the headwidth, headlength, and minshaft.

Comment: Try: quiver(X, Y, mask_1, mask_2, angles='xy', scale_units='xy', scale = 2, width = 0.00008)